# How to capture current date and time in a variable in JSP using JSTL?

Tags: jsp, jstl

How to capture current date and time in a variable in JSP using JSTL?

```
<c:set property="currentTime" value="${System.CurrentTimeMillis()}"/>
```

I am using the above code in my JSP But it has thrown an error.

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The function currentTimeMillis must be used with a prefix when default namespace is not specified.
```

Answer (score 8):

balu, try this one..

```
<jsp:useBean id="now" class="java.util.Date" />

<fmt:formatDate type="time" value="${now}" /><br/>
<fmt:formatDate type="date" value="${now}" /><br/>
<fmt:formatDate type="both" value="${now}" /><br/>
<fmt:formatDate type="both" dateStyle="short" timeStyle="short"
    value="${now}" /><br/>
<fmt:formatDate type="both" dateStyle="medium" timeStyle="medium"
    value="${now}" /><br/>
<fmt:formatDate type="both" dateStyle="long" timeStyle="long"
    value="${now}" /><br/>
<fmt:formatDate pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" value="${now}" /><br/>
```

updated code..

```
<jsp:useBean id="now" class="java.util.Date" />
<jsp:useBean id="bean" class="demo.Sample" />
<c:if test="${bean.timestamp lt now}">
Start date time is in the past.
</c:if>
<c:if test="${bean.timestamp gt now}">
Start date time is in the future.
</c:if>
<c:if test="${bean.timestamp eq now}">
Start date time is identical to now.
</c:if>
```

balu try this one..

Comment: Hi Pirabu thanks for the quick reply but my requirement i need time in long format because i want to compare current date and time with database timestamp value. How can i do this in jsp ?

Answer (score 1):

You got that error because ${System.CurrentTimeMillis()} is INVALID EL expression. There is no System variable in any scopes. NO static method or constant access in EL expression.

JSP Taglib directive:

```
<%@ page import="java.util.Date" ... />
```

Get timestamp as long:

```
<jsp:useBean id="current" class="java.util.Date" />

<c:if test="${current.time > yourTimestampInDb}">
      // .........
</c:if>
```