# How to get System Date without using Java code?

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags

I want to print date without using Java code in jsp file either using jsp tag library or Expression language.

Comment: put anywhere inside the body of your JSP: `<%= new java.util.Date() %>`.

Comment: Set the date from the Servlet to recover the value in EL. But this will be done in Java at some point. Or get the client date using Javascript

Comment: And the problem is?

Comment: @DimaSan, the question specifically asks for a solution that does not use Java code within the JSP. 

This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20773886/how-to-capture-current-date-and-time-in-a-variable-in-jsp-using-jstl

Comment: Set date in your java code(servlet class) as an attribute and retrieve it via Expression language in jsp

Answer (score 0):

In your servlet or controller class

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = new Date();
request.setAttribute("date", dateFormat.format(date));
```

where date is set in HttpServletRequest object

In you jsp,just fetch and display the attribute using EL

```
${date}
```